Can I use Azure's Python SDK to control a UAMI and interact with VMs?
I am developing a command line tool which will work across different cloud platforms to read, start and stop (deallocate) virtual machines. I have this working in AWS with EC2 instances, using boto3, but I don't understand how to achieve the same thing in Azure yet.
In AWS, I have an IAM user whose credentials are used for authentication within the SDK and which has restricted permissions, so nothing sensitive can be started or stopped.
In Azure, I was under the impression that the same thing was possible by assigning a custom role with limited permissions to a UAMI. However, so far, I have only been able to use the Python SDK for Azure by first using az login and signing in with my own credentials.
Is there a way to authenticate using only credentials from the UAMI (e.g. client_id, subscription_id, tenant_id) and have its permissions be the only ones available to the Python script I will write?
The best suggestion I have received so far is to authenticate using ManagedIdentityCredential() like so:
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
client_id = <UAMI_client_id>
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id=client_id)

But this results in the following error, for me:
ImdsCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.
ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.
<some traceback>
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffffb9a32110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I assume this is because I am running my script from my local machine (in much the same way as users of my end product will) and this authentication method seems to be set up for code running within Azure's own environment.
Is there anything similar I can use to authenticate without using any user-specific credentials?

Joe McKeown, Check if below-posted solution works for now?

User assigned managed Identity won't work locally as the managed identity service does not support interactive login, It only works inside a service.
You will have to add your UAMI in Azure Function with required role to Start and Stop VM example- Contributor role.
Assign UAMI to Azure Functions:-

UAMI assigned to Azure Virtual Machine:-

Python Http Trigger code:-
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # Create a credential object using ManagedIdentityCredential
    credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()

    # Create a ComputeManagementClient using the credential
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, '015xxxxxxx7')

    # Now you can use compute_client to manage virtual machines

    return func.HttpResponse("Virtual machine management function executed successfully!")

Function trigger deployed and running successfully from Function app:-

Refer this SO Answer for more details on user assigned managed identity.

The actual solution I used for this was as follows.
Step 1: Create an App Registration (instead of a UAMI).
Step 2: Create a role which grants permission to read, start and deallocate VMs.
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/********-****-****-****-************/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/********-****-****-****-************",
    "properties": {
        "roleName": "VM_Controller_Role",
        "description": "Can start, stop and read VMs",
        "assignableScopes": [
            "/some/desired/scope"
        ],
        "permissions": [
            {
                "actions": [
                    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action",
                    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action",
                    "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read"
                ],
                "notActions": [],
                "dataActions": [],
                "notDataActions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}

Step 3: Assign the App Registration the VM_Controller_Role in the relevant scope.
For me, this meant navigating to:

The target subscription

"Access Control"
"Grant access to this resource (Add role assignment)"

Select the VM_Controller_Role and assign it to the VM_Controller App Registration.





Step 4: Use the Python SDK to authenticate with the App Registration's credentials.
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

# App Registration credentials
client_id = "********-****-****-****-************"
client_secret = "****************************************"
tenant_id = "********-****-****-****-************"
subscription_id = "********-****-****-****-************"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, tenant_id=tenant_id
)

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

This allowed me to get information about VMs in the subscription and start/stop them with calls from the Python script.
